# How to groupby datetime with a lot of NaN

Tags: python

I have a large amount of datasets collected from sensors. I would like to group each column data by every five minutes using the average value.There are loads of NaN values. Can someone help me? The data info and the first 20 rows are presented here:

```
 datasets.info()

 [20 rows x 11 columns]
 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
 RangeIndex: 1083433 entries, 0 to 1083432
 Data columns (total 11 columns):
 Time                1083433 non-null object
 Temp (back)         132639 non-null object
 Temp (front)        104623 non-null object
 Temp (out)          104797 non-null object
 Humidity (back)     132610 non-null object
 Humidity (front)    104718 non-null object
 Humidity (out)      104798 non-null object
 CO2 (front)         104713 non-null object
 CO2 (out)           104790 non-null object
 Door Open           104677 non-null object
 Motion              104415 non-null object
 dtypes: object(11)
 memory usage: 90.9+ MB  

print(datasets.head(20)) 

                     Time Temp (back)  ... Door Open Motion
 0   2018-09-06T07:52:09+02:00       24.79  ...       NaN    NaN
 1   2018-09-06T07:52:09+02:00         NaN  ...       NaN    NaN
 2   2018-09-06T07:53:07+02:00       24.79  ...       NaN    NaN
 3   2018-09-06T07:53:07+02:00         NaN  ...       NaN    NaN
 4   2018-09-06T07:54:06+02:00       24.79  ...       NaN    NaN
 5   2018-09-06T07:54:06+02:00         NaN  ...       NaN    NaN
 6   2018-09-06T07:55:04+02:00        24.8  ...       NaN    NaN
 7   2018-09-06T07:55:04+02:00         NaN  ...       NaN    NaN
 8   2018-09-06T07:56:03+02:00       24.77  ...       NaN    NaN
 9   2018-09-06T07:56:03+02:00         NaN  ...       NaN    NaN
 10  2018-09-06T07:57:01+02:00       24.77  ...       NaN    NaN
 11  2018-09-06T07:57:01+02:00         NaN  ...       NaN    NaN
 12  2018-09-06T07:58:00+02:00       24.77  ...       NaN    NaN
 13  2018-09-06T07:58:00+02:00         NaN  ...       NaN    NaN
 14  2018-09-06T07:58:59+02:00       24.79  ...       NaN    NaN
 15  2018-09-06T07:58:59+02:00         NaN  ...       NaN    NaN
 16  2018-09-06T07:59:58+02:00       24.77  ...       NaN    NaN
 17  2018-09-06T07:59:58+02:00         NaN  ...       NaN    NaN
 18  2018-09-06T08:00:57+02:00       24.82  ...       NaN    NaN
 19  2018-09-06T08:00:57+02:00         NaN  ...       NaN    NaN

 datasets['Time']=pd.to_datetime(datasets['Time'])
 datasets.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5Min')).mean()

  TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or 
  PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'
```

Comment: The datasets are imported from CSV using the following code datasets=pd.read_csv('grafana_data_export.csv',delimiter=';',dtype=str,header=0)